# Azure signalr service context with Angular

Tags: signalr, angular-cli, signalr-service

Wondering if anyone has experience in the azure signalr service(v1.04) and angular cli(v6+).  Having some issues understanding how to get the client context after connecting to the hub.  Any thoughts?

Here's the context of the hub, any help would be appreciated!

```
this.getConnectionInfo().subscribe(info => {
        console.log("INFO", info);

        let options = {
            accessTokenFactory: () => info.accessToken
        };

        this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(info.hubUrl, options)
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build();

        this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {
            console.log('Hub connection started init');

            **[GET hubConnectionContext]**
            console.log('Connection', this.hubConnection);


        })
            .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
```